# How to redirect to login page if the user is not logged in?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing, angular-guards

I have implemented the before login and after login guard so that some users can not access all the pages. My question is when user is not logged in & when they try to enter the unauthorized page such as "localhost:4200/restricted_page" it should be redirected to login page "localhost:4200/login". But I am not being able to redirect to login page. Now it redirects only to localhost:4200 only.

Where should I fix the code?

### before-login.guard

```
export class BeforeLoginGuard implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

        return !this._tokenService.loggedIn();

    }

    constructor(private _tokenService: TokenService) { }
}
```

### after-login.guard

```
export class AfterLoginGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private _tokenService: TokenService) { }

    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

        return this._tokenService.loggedIn();
    }
}
```

### token.service

```
export class TokenService {
    payload(token) {
        const payload = token.split('.')[1];
        //decoding 
        if (typeof (payload) !== 'undefined')
            return JSON.parse(atob(payload));
        return false;
    }

    loggedIn() {
        // return this.isValid();
        const token = this.getToken();
        console.log("token", token);
        if (token) {
            const payload = this.payload(token);
            if (payload) {
                return Object.values(this.iss).indexOf(payload.iss) > -1 ? true : false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `localhost:4200/restricted_page` - this route will have **AfterLoginGuard** .

So in that component

```
   canActivate( next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
       let flag = this._tokenService.loggedIn();
       if(flag ){
          return flag ;
       } else {
          // Navigate to login component. You will have to add router to constructor 
             and then this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return;
       }
       return flag;
    }
```

Ideally I believe there should be only one Auth gaurd with different conditions. But anyways you have developed 2 above will work for you.

Comment: yes thankx .. i was writing this code in before login page and forgot that  had canActivate afterloginguard

Answer (score 1):

Navigate in `canActivate` method depending on loggedin status as:

```
constructor(private router: Router,
            private _tokenService: TokenService) {

}

canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    if(this._tokenService.loggedIn()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        this.router.nvigate['/login']; <=== navigate wherever you want
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

navigate using `@angular/router` by `this.router.navigate([ '/login'])` or just use the `redirectTo` in your route declaration